# How to change remote push notification icon for React Native(android) application

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I have followed this link for push notification implementation within my app 
 https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/tree/a359e5c00954aa324136eaa9808333d6ca246171

at present the default app launcher icon is displayed. 
I want to change it. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you should first add the new icon in all android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-*

notice in all folders that start mipmap-* add new icon with same name with proper resolution

then in your notification object that send you can add it's name

```
{
  largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
  smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default:  "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
}

PushNotification.configure({
  largeIcon: "ic_launcher",
  smallIcon: "ic_notification",
})
```

Comment: How can added this one. please add full answer.

Comment: i added like   PushNotification.configure({
      smallIcon: "ic_notification",})

Comment: How? Could you please explain me?

Comment: The icons *MUST* be placed under `res/mipmap-*` in order for this to work. The Android Studio IDE tends to want to put images under `res/drawable-*` if you do a drag-and-drop or copy-and-paste of an image file, so move them if necessary

Comment: @KiritModi Thank you! This is correct way to setup GCM notifications without server changes.

Comment: @Mohamed How can I show a remote image as largeIcon

Comment: @KrishanKumarMourya this plugin is deprecated you should use react-native-firebase

Comment: what about ios??

Answer (score 32):

You have to follow some rules for notification icon [link](https://material.io/design/iconography/#)

First, generate notification icons [link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit) of all sizes. and put the icon name `ic_notification`.

Then move all sizes `ic_notification` in the respective folder in the `android/app/main/res/mipmap` folder and add below line in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

`<meta-data  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />`

Comment: this is a great answer, one can also use this service to create the icons: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html

Comment: @jamesmurphy In case of local notifications, you need to pass smallIcon and largeIcon values during building the local notification object (as per these info https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#local-notifications).

Comment: One important thing to add here is that the notification images should only be white and gray. If you add coloured images, they are ignored. Something that I realised after wasting a good few hours. You can use this amazing tool to generate appropriate notification images - http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_notification

Comment: @rahulworld, what if I want to add the background color to my logo? There are many logos that have background color, how are they working? Any idea?

Comment: Use this answer for getting coloured notification icon badge for android. https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1326#issuecomment-616743061

Answer (score 9):

In AndroidManifest.xml add the below line

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification" />
```

create custom icon ic_notification and add them to mipmap and drawable folders

Comment: what about ios??

Answer (score 8):

I found solution by adding below code in AndroidManifest.xml before application closing tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```

Generate the notification icons of all sizes at [Notification Icon Generator](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit). On the Notification Icon Generator site, set the following option before generating and downloading the files. Note, if you use your own image, the background must be transparent:

1. File name:  `notification_icon`

Once you download the files, extract all the contents into Android > src > main > res

Comment: what about ios??

Answer (score 1):

I found solution by adding below code in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_notification" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APGi0.png)